# How to do smooth corners or super-ellipse in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, sketch-3, sketchapp

Sketch 47 just implemented [smooth corners](https://blog.sketchapp.com/introducing-libraries-and-smooth-corners-in-sketch-47-2abc5dfc1fb3) and Apple already uses [super-ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAwAa.jpg) for app icons since iOS 7, is there a way to round the corners of your UIViews the same way?

The super-ellipse formula (1 = |x/60|^5 + |y/60|^5) works for app-icons but when adjusting for larger sizes looks a little weird.

Comment: no there is not but you can make the background transparent and set a background or something else with rounded corners